# Copying files from a saved FileField to an UploadedFile in Django

Tags: django, file-upload, filefield, django-file-upload

I need to save files, not from request.FILES, but from another saved record.

Here's the code for the model record:

```
class Foo(models.Model)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class FooFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='foo_folder')
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='files')

class RealRecord(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    awesome_file=models.FileField(upload_to='awesome')
    mediocre_file=models.FileField(upload_to='mediocre')
```

And the view (in this case `MyForm` is a model form that saves to RealRecord):

```
def example(request, record=1, template_name="form.html")
    foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=record)
    SAVED_FILES = {}
    for file in foo_obj.files.all():
         SAVED_FILES[file.name]=file.file
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST, files=SAVED_FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            # rest of view
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

So the thing is basically a `FieldFile` is being used as an `UploadedFile` object.

Each `Foo` will have a `FooFile` record with the name `awesome_file` and another with the name `mediocre_file`, matching up with the required fields in `RealRecord`.

The crazy thing is, this totally validates. *However*, the problem is that in the resulting record that is created, both awesome_file and mediocre_file have their path in "foo_folder". But I don't want the files in "foo_folder", I want them to be in the path that I specified for each field in `RealRecord`.

So I guess I am wondering what I can do to the `FieldFile` values coming from `FooField` so that they behave like a traditional UploadedFile and get the `upload_to` and `path` values of their respective fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awww... you guys! I was really hoping someone would come up with an answer. Anyway, I was able to come up with my own solution; not sure if it's the optimal one but it works.

I made a slight mod to `FooFile` so it also stores the content_type of the uploaded file:

```
class FooFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='foo_folder')
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=254) # max length given by RFC 4288 
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='files')
```

and then, in the view, I create a `SimpleUploadedFile` object for each `FooFile` record:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
import os

def example(request, record=1, template_name="form.html")
    foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=record)
    SAVED_FILES = {}
    for saved_file in foo_obj.files.all():
        SAVED_FILES[file.name]=SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.basename(saved_file.file.path), saved_file.file.read(), saved_file.content_type)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST, files=SAVED_FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            # rest of view
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

Comment: The finished code is available on github: https://github.com/JordanReiter/django-unauth-posting if anyone finds it useful, please let me know. Also, please fork and improve it!